# how to search from the last column of a csv file using shell script and the result should contain all the columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

My csv file (heart.csv) is like this: [image: heart.csv]

```
age,sex,cp,trtbps,chol,fbs,restecg,thalachh,exng,oldpeak,slp,caa,thall,output
63,1,3,145,233,1,0,150,0,2.3,0,0,1,1
54,1,0,110,239,0,1,126,1,2.8,1,1,3,0
41,0,1,130,204,0,0,172,0,1.4,2,0,2,1
70,1,0,145,174,0,1,125,1,2.6,0,0,3,0
62,1,1,120,281,0,0,103,0,1.4,1,1,3,0
57,0,0,120,354,0,1,163,1,0.6,2,0,2,1
```

I want to search the CSV file column by column.... I want only those rows which column  `output` has value `1` or `0`. I want to get this result using **Shell Script**.

I've tried this:

```sh
echo "please enter pattern to search: "
read pattern
awk -v patt="$pattern" -F',' '$14 == patt' heart.csv
```

It worked for every other column. it's just NOT working for the last column.

The output file should be like this (with the last column being '1'):

```
63,1,3,145,233,1,0,150,0,2.3,0,0,1,1
41,0,1,130,204,0,0,172,0,1.4,2,0,2,1
57,0,0,120,354,0,1,163,1,0.6,2,0,2,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your csv file has windows line endings `\r\n` instead of linux line endings `\n`. Therefore every value from the file's last column ends with `\r` and prevents `$14 == patt` from ever being true (unless you have `patt="...\r"`).

To fix this, you can convert your csv file using `dos2unix heart.csv`.

If you want to keep the windows line endings (even in the output) and have GNU awk (`check awk --version`), then you can use

```
awk -v patt="$pattern" -F, -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r\n' '$14 == patt'
```

Comment: it's not working. it's showing an error message:- awk: 1: unexpected character '\'

Comment: Sorry, I missed one `-v` before `ORS=`. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

> how to search from the last column of a csv file

I suggest using `grep` and using a regex matching all lines ending with `,1`:

```
grep ',1$' heart.csv
```

Output:

```
63,1,3,145,233,1,0,150,0,2.3,0,0,1,1
41,0,1,130,204,0,0,172,0,1.4,2,0,2,1
57,0,0,120,354,0,1,163,1,0.6,2,0,2,1
```

Comment: it's not giving me any kind of output at all.

Comment: @ethanmeem In that case, try `dos2unix` first as Socowi suggested: `dos2unix < heart.csv | grep ',1$'`

Comment: sorry, altering the input file is not allowed

Comment: @ethanmeem `dos2unix < heart.csv | grep ',1$'` does not alter the input file.

Answer (score 0):

[`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a handy bundle of utilities for working with CSV files, including a `csvgrep`:

```sh
$ csvgrep -c output -m 1 heart.csv                                                              age,sex,cp,trtbps,chol,fbs,restecg,thalachh,exng,oldpeak,slp,caa,thall,output
63,1,3,145,233,1,0,150,0,2.3,0,0,1,1
41,0,1,130,204,0,0,172,0,1.4,2,0,2,1
57,0,0,120,354,0,1,163,1,0.6,2,0,2,1
```

If your file doesn't have the header row, you can specify column numbers too: `csvgrep -H -c 14 -m 1 heart.csv`

(It's smart enough to work with both CR and CRLF style line endings, if that's the problem you're running into)